# Can a label in the .kv file in Kivy reference a global singletons public variables directly

Tags: python, kivy, global-variables, singleton, datastore

I have a data store singleton declared in my python file as follows:

```
# Singletons
Configsettings = None

class CNCConfigurationSettings():
    StoredSettingsStore = None
    DynamicSettingsStore = {"ConnectingComPortState":"Idle"}
    def __init__(self, \*\*kwargs):
        super().__init__(\*\*kwargs)
        with open("SPSJSettingsFile.json", "r") as infile:
        JSONFileSettings = infile.read()
        self.StoredSettingsStore = json.loads(JSONFileSettings)

    def __del__(self):
        print('Writing Config Data')
        with open("SPSJSettingsFile.json", "w") as outfile:
             outfile.write(json.dumps(self.StoredSettingsStore, indent=4))

<snip>

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Configsettings = CNCConfigurationSettings()
```

This is global. and is used to handle all settings in my program.

when I try to connect a label text in the .kv file to a variable stored in a dictionary in the singleton:

```
Label:
    size_hint:1,.1
    text: Configsettings.StoredSettingsStore["DefaultComPort"]
```

I get an error.  I know normally the singleton can be part of the view object and accessed through root.<...>  but I want this object to be available all through my code not just local to the view object.   Any Kivy experts be able to help here?

I tried to build with the singleton reference but python has an exception as follows:

```
 NameError: name 'Configsettings' is not defined
   File "C:\Users\mroche\PycharmProjects\WorkshopCNCController\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 240, in create_handler
     return eval(value, idmap), bound_list
   File "C:\Users\mroche\PycharmProjects\WorkshopCNCController\CNCView.kv", line 92, in <module>
     text: Configsettings.DynamicSettingsStore["ConnectingComPortState"]
 
   File "C:\Users\mroche\PycharmProjects\WorkshopCNCController\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 694, in _apply_rule
     value, bound = create_handler(
   File "C:\Users\mroche\PycharmProjects\WorkshopCNCController\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 243, in create_handler
     raise BuilderException(rule.ctx, rule.line,
```

I expected it would access the Global singleton